# iOS - Making sense of velocityInView on UIPanGesture

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

I'm using a UIPanGesture to return velocityInView and from what I gather it's supposed to be returning points per second. What I am getting is numbers in the hundreds of millions and a lot of zeros... I'm not moving my mouse that quickly in the simulator.

I think...

Thanks in advance for any help/advice you have.

Edit: Requested Code.

Displaying / Calling

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || 
        recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        CGPoint vel = [recognizer velocityInView:myScrollView];
        //[self doSpinAnimationWithVelocity:vel.x];
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velocity - X-Axis - %d ", vel.x]);
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velocity - Y-Axis - %d ", vel.y]);
    }
}
```

[Image here of output since I'm still below 10 rep](http://www.mytheral.com/storage/Screen%20shot%202011-02-02%20at%202.50.42%20PM.png)

Comment: If it makes a difference I'm only capturing the x-axis at the moment.

Comment: the y-axis is giving similar information as well.

Comment: Show the code where you call velocityInView and how you are showing the numbers.

Comment: You should be using %f for floats and not %d. See if that helps the printing.

Comment: That brings the numbers down very close to what I was expecting.

I think this did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without your code its hard to say...

CGPoint is made up of CGFloats, depending on how you are printing them you could be getting unexpected results

The view you pass into velocityInView: must be in the view hierarchy, check it by looking at the window property on the view before you pass it into the velocityInView: method

Comment: This answer was technically correct but Matt hit it on the head in the comments above. Thanks all.

Comment: if you give a person a fish, the person eats for a day, if you teach a person to fish they program for a lifetime...

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but another tip: Check out NSStringFromCGPoint() and family:

```
-(void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
   if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged || 
       recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
   {
      CGPoint vel = [recognizer velocityInView:myScrollView];
      NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(vel));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like velocityInView: returns a CGPoint, representing horizontal and vertical components (basically, it's a vector). Since the velocity is broken into these two components, you have to be careful how you analyze the values. If your looking more for speed and not velocity, you would take the magnitude of the vector, i.e. something like:

```
CGFloat magnitude = sqrtf((velocityPoint.x * velocityPoint.x) + (velocityPoint.y * velocityPoint.y));
```

Comment: Just for clarity, this was posted before my code sample and image.