# How do I calculate the speed of which a user drags an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have an image that the user can drag to the right and it will spring back when the user releases it. I want to execute some code when a user drags it quickly and releases it. Now I have a very awkward requirement that the user can drag the image, then keep it still for any length of time (for example 5 seconds), then drag it quickly and release it. As long as the image is moving above a certain speed when it is released, it will execute the code. If it falls below the minimum speed, it executes some different code. So that means I can't calculate the length of time between the beginning of the gesture and the end and execute the code depending on the length of time. What can I do? I guess I somehow need to know the speed at which the image is moving in it's last 500 milliseconds before the gesture ends. However I've hit a brick wall figuring out how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Can you please include an explanation and possible example code with your answer as that would be a great help.

Comment: Take a look at the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` `velocityInView` method.

Comment: Could you post some code? As @bobnoble mentioned, if you're using a gesture recognizer, then obtaining velocity is trivial.

Comment: I am using a UIPanGestureRecognizer. I will post some code today when I get to my computer. Why wouldn't need to get the velocity with a UIPanGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more on the internet, I finally answered my own question.

I worked out what I needed to do:

My UIPanGestureRecognizer:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan3:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer3
```

Get the velocity of the users finger moving across the screen:

```
CGPoint vel = [recognizer velocityInView:self.myView];
```

Then:

```
if (vel.x > /*value*/) {
// Your code
}
```

I was about to give up, but no! I got there in the end. Thanks for everyones help. I've upvoted one or two answers because they were helpful. bobnoble actually gave the suggestion to use velocityInView and I found this other stack overflow question which gave me the info I needed: [iOS - Making sense of velocityInView on UIPanGesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878901/ios-making-sense-of-velocityinview-on-uipangesture)

Answer (score 1):

If you get the start X,Y coordinates of when the image is dragged, and the X,Y coordinates for when the mouse is released, you can use pythagoras' theorm to calculate the distance between the two points: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem

Also, if you start a timer when the mouse is moved (and mouse button is down), and stop it in the mouseup event, you can calculate the speed using the time and distance (speed = distance / time)

edit following comments:

```
point delayedMousePos;
point previousMousePos;

bool secondDrag = false;
bool isStopped = false;

var timeFirstStopped;
var positionCount = 0;

array previousMousePositions[3];

// timer which monitors mouse position (set to an interval of say, 10ms)
function timerMonitorMousePos_Elapsed() {
    point currentMousePos = getMousePos();

    if (isStopped == false) {
        if (positionCount >= 2) {
            array_shift(previousMousePositions); // remove the first element of the array and move everything down to reindex numerical array to start counting from zero 
            positionCount = 2; // keep positionCount within array bounds
        }

        previousMousePositions[positionCount] = currentMousePos; // add the new position to the end of the 'stack'
        positionCount++;
    }

    if (currentMousePos == previousMousePos) { // start check for stationary
        isStopped = true;
        if (timeFirstStopped == null) {
            timeFirstStopped = NOW();
        } else {
            if (NOW() - timeFirstStopped >= 500) { // we have been stopped for at least 500ms (assumes time is counted in milliseconds)
                secondDrag = true;
                // previousMousePositions[0] = the mouse position 30ms before the mouse stopped
            }
        }
    } else {
        isStopped = false;
        timeFirstStopped = null;
    }

    previousMousePos = currentMousePos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in my question, my awkward circumstances mean I can't do that because the user needs to be able to pause half way through dragging and then move the image quickly and release and still activate the code. I need to really calculate the final speed before the user releases the image. If that makes sense. It mustn't calculate the speed from start to finish, just the last millisecond of the movement before release.

Comment: you could use another timer to monitor the mouse position to see if it had stopped moving while still dragging, then use a boolean switch to let your mousemove event know that the next time it moves, it will be the 'second drag'.. you could also use this timer to select a different mouse coordinate to calculate your distance/speed from?

Comment: I don't think that will work as I need it to. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe that this wouldn't allow the user to drag the image really slowly, taking around 10 seconds and the quickly move it and let it go, without stopping at all.

Comment: check if the x/y coordinates have remained the same for > 500ms ?

Comment: That still wouldn't be perfect, but it would be better. Could you put that into code? How would I check the coordinates in the last milliseconds?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know objective c, so can't post a proper example, but I have edited my answer to include some psuedo code that might hopefully help. I see now though that someone has commented with something that might be more useful - either way - good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a timer.  I would just save the starting date/time along with x,y position when the dragging starts.

When the dragging has ended, save the ending date/time and position.  From those information, I can calculate the distance in pixel and duration in milliseconds.

Comment: I don't think that would work as I need it to, because it wouldn't allow the user to move the image slowly at the start and then just before releasing, move it fast and release. I think all I need to be able to do is calculate the image's speed in the last 500 milliseconds and the that speed determines whether the code is executed.